# Can an Android view have an aspect ratio, fill the parent horizontally and be centered in the parent?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to embed an image between the rows of a RecyclerView (As another ViewType/ViewHolder). Said image must have a 9:5 aspect ratio, with a max height of 600px so it doesn't grow huge on bigger phones or tablets, and therefore must be centered horizontally if it's size doesn't match the parent width due to aspect ratio resizing.

Is this achievable without custom code? I tried ConstraintLayout and PercentFrameLayout and both seem to ignore the android:maxHeight criteria.

Comment: Max height of 600px-  you don't actually want that.  You want a max height in terms of dp.  Doing it in px doesn't actually control how big it is, on a high density display it will be 1/4 the size of a low density display.

Comment: @GabeSechan Valid criticism, i will consider that after actually getting all the other criteria working.

Comment: I usually resize images (also in a RecyclerView) after they are shown. In this case I get an image width, calculate it's height and set.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `ConstraintLayout` using guidelines. Set your guidelines `600px` apart and constrain the `ImageView` to the guidelines: top and bottom. These constraints will keep the image from growing beyond `600px`. Here is a [video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FitJ6.gif) of what happens when I move the bottom guideline up and down. Below is the XML for the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineTop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="0px" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineBottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="600px" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineBottom"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="9:5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineTop"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```